# I have a 3rd party digital signature Java applet that is having issue on "some" client computers, I know how to verify the version but . 

Tags: java, javascript

I wish I had more specifics, I don't have browser or java versions of the client computers having issues. As it stands right now I have a java applet that just checks the version if the client clicks it. Is there a way to check version before the page loads? I'd rather be proactive than reactive on the page. I've checked documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) but without having access to the digital signature applet code, am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Should have been more clear! It is literally an application that allows you to sign your name digitally.

Comment: You know how when one screws up, they get so mortified it leads to multiple screw ups in quick succession? That just happened Sigh... Yes, my employer says that while we investigate further and acquire the necessary data from the client, if the run time version is checked, displayed to the client, and if necessary point them to update their java, this will be sufficient in the interim. Rather than waiting to find out that the applet didn't work after clicking submit then having to click another button to check java, I'd rather have the page let them know of an issue before hand.

Comment: deployJava.js is the correct answer. Took a day to get it functioning correctly, still working on the final version, I'll post the code here when completed. Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deployJava.js` mentioned in the deployment advice is the best option for this applet.  If a suitable minimum version of Java is not available (and the end-user cannot or will not install it when prompted), the applet will not run.

---

Having said that, there *are* other options.  Such as:

- Applet based solutions:  (Although I developed both these applets, I now use `deployJava.js`.)

  1. The [JRE Version Checker](http://pscode.org/jre.html) applet.  Place it in the same page as the target applet in order to support the version checking.
  2. [Wrapplet](http://pscode.org/wrapplet/).  'Wraps' the target applet and offers (amongst other things) version checking with fall-back options.
- Use JavaScript to check the version.  (And do whatever you want if it fails.) E.G.

---

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(
    "<p>java.version: " +
    java.lang.System.getProperty("java.version"));
document.write(
    "<p>java.specification.version: " +
    java.lang.System.getProperty("java.specification.version"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Final code for Version Java checking. I'm leaving this as an example in case someone (like myself) was having an issue getting deployJava.js to function.

[using this app for signing a name to documents](http://www.izhuk.com/painter/)

```
 <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>       
<script >
    if (deployJava.versionCheck('1.4+')) {
        var dir = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        var url = dir + "plugin2.jnlp";
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.4+');
    } else {
        document.location.href="http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp";
    }
</script>
```